# UIImage not loading in the first instance in DetailViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, master-detail

I have a master-detail application. I list all images from the application documents folder in the MasterViewController tableview. On the click of each tableview item, I load the image in the DetailViewController, which has a UIImageView. The problem I am facing is that, the images does not load in the first instance, when I click a tableview item. I just see the message "The detail view content goes here", in the DetailViewController. If I go back and try again, it will work just fine. Its just the first time that the image wont load.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (!self.detailViewController) {
    self.detailViewController = [[PtmDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PtmDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
}
//NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];

NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.fPath];
UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
self.detailViewController.imgViewer.image = thumbNail;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the view of `detailViewController` doesn't have time to load. So you are setting the image to the `nil` UIImageView (it's not initialized yet).

Try adding a property `UIImage *thumb` to `detailViewController` and then in detailViewController's `viewDidLoad` add

```
imgViewer.image=self.thumb;
```

And in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` change

```
UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
self.detailViewController.imgViewer.image = thumbNail;
```

to

```
UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
self.detailViewController.thumb = thumbNail;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, first time either `self.fpath` is coming `nil` or there is no image in that `path`. Check the `imgData` is having `valur or nil` at first time. Then show your image,

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.fpath]
```